# Should HTML comments be stripped when validating answer length?

Tags: bug, status-declined, answers, character-limit

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545186/do-you-use-protected-visibility/1545194#1545194) used an HTML comment to subvert the "Your answer is too short" error.

Should HTML comments not be counted as part of the length of an answer? (Similar to how spaces aren't counted.)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Comment: Note: View the source and you'll see that it actually *is* an answer.

Answer (score 7):

No.

Comment: I needed you in when I was writing my English final in high school.

Answer (score 5):

I don't understand the problem. It was a fitting answer to a fitting question. If it was a legitimate question the answer would have been down-voted into oblivion or simply ignored.

As for the HTML comments, these instances are rare and most answer are longer than one sentence. I see no reason to actually change anything.

Comment: Then you should advocate to remove the answer length limit!

Comment: I do. In the instance of comments, it's somewhat useful, but for answers... Sometimes "yes" is yes and we should leave it at that.

Answer (score 4):

If you really want to go through the effort to post a short answer, then fine. I don't think it would be worth the effort to strip out all the possible ways of cheating that system.

One word answers will probably get downvoted anyway. And zero word answers should be flagged as spam, since they are just wasting space.

Comment: Some questions just *beg* for one word answers. They cry out for them in piteous little voices that I can not deny. 'Course, I generally put them in the comments, but still...