# Should users be able to circumvent the minimum character limits by adding HTML comments to their posts?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should HTML comments be stripped when validating answer length?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25344/should-html-comments-be-stripped-when-validating-answer-length)

See my answer here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/123638/155556
(now only 10K+ viewable (since the OP was deleted))

I was able to make my answer "" (yes that was on purpose)

In the end you can read the edits to the answer and get the point, but why should I be able to do that?

I assume [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

Comment: Ssshhhhhhh...don't tell them...they'll steal it from us!

Comment: @Bobby :-P haha I left you a message here

Comment: On a more serious note, I can remember that discussion mostly about comments...the result was that people came up with *many* creative ways to circumvent whatever was in place.

Comment: @Bobby I promise. ^_^

Comment: Did the great circle of meta just begin again? I seem to remember discussing this sometime in 2009. (Although back in *my* day, we had much more elegant solutions than mere HTML hacks. Bah!)

Comment: @mmyers hehe I was't hear waaaay back in 2009. But as the old saying goes: "History repeats itself". ^_^

Comment: Yeah, I've heard that one before.

Comment: Seriously @random ... :-(

Comment: I came close to re-opening this. On the one hand, we can't have people with diamonds next to their name deliberately circumventing quality filters. On the other hand, the guy does own the place. It's his party, his booze and then there's the stuff that he provides that we actually want. This would break out into unicorns stabbing themselves with their own horns. That's rather hard to deny. I'm not locking this, I'm just asking anyone that votes to re-open to **strongly** consider if this will actually result in something constructive or meme bait. That's all, nothing less, nothing more.

Comment: @TimPost ahhh, but what **is** constructive here on meta? http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/107073/155556

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA My decision was basically this: Let's have fun spanking Joel while making light of what sparked this over a single answer, or raise the question in a less antagonistic way. That's what I mean by _constructive_.

Comment: @TimPost haha I am not trying to be antagonistic :-P I am just wondering why I should be allowed to do it. Edit away as much as you want to make it sound better ^_^

Comment: @Tim - I hope my answer wasn't misconstrued; it was meant as a meta joke :)  I find nothing wrong with using html comment to circumvent the filter, so long as you have a legitimate, good reason.  I'd say Joel's post is the best example of a legitimate reason.

Comment: This is one of those times where I feel moderation should be basically hands off. As I said, I'm not locking it, if it turns into green orange and yellow slime mixed with egg, well, you should have edited more :) I Agree with @random's choice to close it in the original form, or it would be open by now. This is your question, it's up to you to edit it, not me :)

Comment: Thanks you @RobertHarvey ^_^ Good title :-)

Comment: Examples of where this is actually being used to circumvent low-quality filters? And preferably examples drawn from somewhere other than Meta...

Comment: @CodyGray: I'm not sure.  Changed title to "Quality Filters" which includes the minimum character limits.

Comment: @CodyGray I am not sure atm.... I would do a search but I am not the best at those queries....

Comment: @CodyGray: Confirmed; I just tested it here on Meta. Characters in HTML comments are not considered when evaluating question quality for the "It does not meet our quality standards" block.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/123659/102937

Comment: I'm not asking whether this loophole exists. I know it does, I've used it before while deleting an answer. The question is, are other people actually using it in a way that is harmful? It's amusing to cite Joel as an example, but that misses the point.

Comment: Haha @RobertHarvey haha I like it how my question went from `non-constructive` to a `duplicate` ^_^

Comment: @Neil - you might be interested http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123665/should-duplicate-standards-be-different-on-meta

Comment: @AdamRackis thanks ^_^ (and Neal is with an `A` :-P)

Comment: Oops - my apologies :-)

Answer (score 18):

I wholeheartedly support fixing this problem.  I'm sick and tired of people [using this trick](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116918/155403) to get around the quality filters!

Comment: HA! `+1` from me :-P

Comment: @amanaPlan - HA!  Nice edit :)

Comment: I thought so :-)

Comment: -1 for jealousy that your answer is more amusing than mine, and is also voted higher.  SUPPORT VOTE ENVY!

Comment: There's an odd dynamic going on here. The question gets 10 downvotes, but this answer gets 12 upvotes? :o Apparently it's OK for the OP to do this, but not the CEO of Stack Exchange.

Comment: @Robert - hehe - the idea struck me...looks like othes were amused too.  I'm just glad Adam Davis's answer is back on top - that's the real answer.  The filter bypass is not really a problem, and, honestly, only ever seems to be used judiciously and intelligently.

Comment: @RobertHarvey haha Thanks for the support :-)   That's where SE's world domination plan comes into effect ^_^

Comment: This is a very valid point. I don't disagree with you.

Answer (score 16):

It seems like minor enough of an issue that it can be dealt with by hand using the flagging tools.  If it were an epidemic, then "fixing" it might be worthwhile - and could consist solely of converting the sanitized markdown to HTML, then making sure the HTML output meets the size requirements.

But I don't think that's necessary.  Let people have their little toys, and you may avert larger problems.

Comment: Sounds good ^_^

Comment: _'If it were an epidemic...'_ And when those spammers can post constructive white-/other-invisible-space...

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment I don't believe invisible text is rendered to the final webpage, so it doesn't affect search engines or visitors.  Haven't checked recently, though.  Look at the page source and see.

Comment: @AdamDavis I don't think so, I was just playin'.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment NO FUN HAVING ALLOWED. >:(

Comment: I need a second upvote so I can get this answer on top (always) ....

Comment: Probably the most sensible answer by far.

Answer (score 5):

I think that this question (and especially the answer by Jeff) really covers the SE stance on things like this:

[Zero-width non-joiner allows unclickable titles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44011/zero-width-non-joiner-allows-unclickable-titles/44113#44113)

Especially this line:

> The short answer is "don't do that", and the longer answer is "if you
>   keep doing that, there will be consequences."

*NOTE: This is just in addition to [Adam Davis' answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/123643/168428), which I think fully covers this specific case*.

Comment: -1: Needs more invisible material.

Comment: *"if you keep doing that, there will be consequences."*  Yeah, like being limited to only being able to change your name once every 30 days.