# Can't Seem to comment out a link

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign, markdown, markdown-rendering

When testing out [The HTML comment Length hack](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/123641/155556)
 and I was trying to make the *Duplicate Link* message a comment itself I came across this curious predicament:

This is the markup:

```
<!-- **Possible Duplicate:**  >
<!--[Should HTML comments be stripped when validating answer length?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25344/should-html-comments-be-stripped-when-validating-answer-length)  -->
```

But it looks like this:

Should HTML comments be stripped when validating answer length?-->

---

Shouldn't the link be commented out?

Why is it showing as plain-text, is this a Markdown or SE issue?

Comment: First you want to eliminate the "feature" altogether, now you're filing bug reports about it?

Comment: @CodyGray You misunderstand. I never wanted to _eliminate_ it. I was wondering why I was able to do it. If elimination is necessary, then so be it.

Comment: Are you going to spawn a new meta question for every little issue you find with this?

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn No I will not. I am just curious. And if people do not like my curiosity, I guess they can vote me down....

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn You must be new to his mode of operation -- it's really quite simple: 1) Notice something on SO. 2) Write a meta post about it immediately

Answer (score 5):

I'm pretty sure it's just the way that Markdown runs through things.

```
[Should HTML comments be stripped when validating answer length?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25344/should-html-comments-be-stripped-when-validating-answer-length)
```

will become

```
<a href="https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25344/should-html-comments-be-stripped-when-validating-answer-length">Should HTML comments be stripped when validating answer length?</a>
```

first, which creates this:

```
<!-- **Possible Duplicate:**  >
<!--<a href="https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25344/should-html-comments-be-stripped-when-validating-answer-length">Should HTML comments be stripped when validating answer length?</a>  -->
```

Then the Markdown parser starts removing HTML that it doesn't allow:

It removes `<!-- **Possible Duplicate:**  >` first.

Then it sees `<!--<a href="https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25344/should-html-comments-be-stripped-when-validating-answer-length">` as **one** unsupported element and removes it.

Then it removes the `</a>`.

And you're left with `Should HTML comments be stripped when validating answer length?  -->`.

**Edit:** As [explained before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120422/141525), Markdown just goes from `<` to `>`. It doesn't look at comment syntax.